# What is the CMOS cache battery on the Atari STacy motherboard?

Tags: atari

I am restoring an Atari STacy, and it is a notoriously hard device to open — I am planning to replace the floppy drive and internal CMOS battery in one go... but while I know the floppy is an Epson SMD 380, I do not know the exact spec of the battery.

I would rather not open the machine and leave it half-assembled for a week. Anyone have a tip on the battery type?

I found this picture of the STacy's innards: [image]

Comment: Your image from [Atari Stacy computer](http://oldcomputers.net/stacy.html) has a third-party expansion board obscuring the battery and appears to have a Li–SOCl2 battery of its own

Comment: Oh. I have not seen the inside of mine so I did not realize that was the case. Thanks!

Comment: Updated with better, not-obscured picture.

Comment: Just for clarification, while the battery in older systems uses to feed a NVRAM it is near always an indicator the system has a RTC; while you could replace the original persistent RAM with more modern NVRAM such as flash, the real time clock system needs to be always powered. I am not used to the STacy, but if there was some sort of relatively large cavity easily accessible from the outside (such an unused expansion slot) I would recommend to add an AA battery carrier to ease future replacements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Stacy is essential a Mega-ST. The battery used is a standard 3 volt [CR2354](https://www.panasonic-batteries.com/de/spezial/knopfzellen/coin-lithium-cr2354) cell ... except with soldering wires welded on. Panasonic offers them [in various configurations](https://de.rs-online.com/web/c/batterien-und-ladegerate/batterien/knopfzellen-batterien/?r=f&redirect-relevancy-data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searchHistory=%7B%22enabled%22%3Atrue%7D&searchTerm=CR2354&searchType=KEYWORD_SINGLE_ALPHA_NUMERIC), the [90 degree version CR-2354/HFN](https://de.rs-online.com/web/p/knopfzellen-batterien/7450878) *might* work with the Stacy. Note, there are different versions with wide and small soldering stripes. I can't tell which one goes with the Stacy without opening mine.